# What's a good general way of catching a StackOverflow exception in C#?

Tags: c#, exception, stack-overflow

If I have a method that I know could potentially recurse infinitely, but I can't reliably predict what conditions/parameters would cause it, what's a good way in C# of doing this:

```
try
{
  PotentiallyInfiniteRecursiveMethod();
}
catch (StackOverflowException)
{
  // Handle gracefully.
}
```

Obviously in the main thread you can't do this, but I've been told a few times it's possible to do it using threads or AppDomain's, but I've never seen a working example. Anybody know how this is done reliably?

Comment: Can you redesign your algorithm?

Comment: It's not necessarily my algorithm; for example the `Transform` method on an `XslCompiledTransform` object will break if the XSLT has a recursive template in it.

Comment: It's not necessarily my XSLT, and that's only one example anyway.

Comment: +1, very interesting question. My first gut reaction was: “that can’t be possible in principle” but since the exception unwinds the stack anyway, there’s really no reason why this can’t be done.

Answer (score 11):

You can't. From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stackoverflowexception.aspx)

> Starting with the .NET Framework
>   version 2.0, a StackOverflowException 
>   object cannot be caught by a try-catch
>   block and the corresponding process is
>   terminated by default. Consequently,
>   users are advised to write their code
>   to detect and prevent a stack
>   overflow. For example, if your
>   application depends on recursion, use
>   a counter or a state condition to
>   terminate the recursive loop. Note
>   that an application that hosts the
>   common language runtime (CLR) can
>   specify that the CLR unload the
>   application domain where the stack
>   overflow exception occurs and let the
>   corresponding process continue. For
>   more information, see
>   ICLRPolicyManager Interface and
>   Hosting Overview.

Comment: Actually, from that snippet I'd assume that you CAN; it specifically says that a process will continue if the application domain where the exception occurred is unloaded. That implies it's possible to run the method in it's own application domain; my question is, how can this be done?

Comment: This link might prove useful: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd380850.aspx . It described how to load new application domains. Perhaps that might be the most graceful idea. But hosting a whole new AppDomain seems a bit overkill.. Can you validate the XSLT for circular references?

Comment: That's not trivial to do, but that's not the point; I'm looking for a general solution regardless of what's causing the stack overflow.

Comment: For a more general solution, I do think you will need to dive into that domain. I don't think it comes any easier. :(

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to catch StackOverflowException, but you can do something with unhandled exception:

```
static void Main()
{
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += 
  new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(CurrentDomain_UnhandledException);
}

static void CurrentDomain_UnhandledException
  (object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
{
  try
  {
    Exception ex = (Exception)e.ExceptionObject;

    MessageBox.Show("Whoops! Please contact the developers with the following" 
          + " information:\n\n" + ex.Message + ex.StackTrace, 
          "Fatal Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Stop);
  }
  finally
  {
    Application.Exit();
  }
}
```

Comment: That won't fire on a StackOverflow exception, I've tried; at least not from within AppDomain.CurrentDomain.